# Postgresql use first row value in next

Tags: postgresql

Hello I have table like this:

```
  A | b | c |
--------------
 1  | 0 | 
 2  | 1 | 
 3  | 1 | 
 4  | 2 |
```

I need result like this:

```
 A | b | c |
--------------
 1  | 0 | 0     -   0 + 0     0 b value from first row   ,   0 - b value
 2  | 1 | 1     -   0 + 1     0 b value from first row   ,   1 - b value
 3  | 1 | 1     -   0 + 1     0 b value from first row   ,   1 - b value
 4  | 2 | 2     -   0 + 2     0 b value from first row   ,   2 - b value
```

Column C it is b + first row from b.
I now about LAG to get preview value, but how about always first.
How to get result like shown in table?

PostgreSQL 10

Regards

Comment: What result are you trying to get?  Which of those two tables represents what you already have?

Comment: Both present the same case. Column C is going to be calculated. At the begining it is empty.

Comment: Ok, i.ve corected my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
SELECT A, b,
       b + FIRST_VALUE(b) OVER (ORDER BY A) c
FROM tablename
```

Or if you want to update the table:

```
UPDATE tablename  
SET c = b + (SELECT DISTINCT FIRST_VALUE(b) OVER (ORDER BY A) FROM tablename)
```

Or:

```
UPDATE tablename  
SET c = b + (SELECT b FROM tablename ORDER BY A LIMIT 1)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bf6a220d3fdbae3e26d2184202bf499f).

Comment: Thank you for your dedication.